# objective-c replacing telprompt built in call dialog

Tags: objective-c, telprompt

using telprompt:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", self.phoneNumber]]];
```

you get a built in alert/messagebox  like this:

[image]

is there a way to create a custom messagebox for telprompt? or making a call with another method?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. `telprompt` enable user to go back to the app after the call. If you use the `tel scheme`, you can display a custom `UIAlertView`, but you can't go back to your app after the call.